# Why should I have an account with Stack Overflow anymore?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, user-accounts, post-ban

SO is always throwing this error when I post a question (meaning that I've been found to have poor questions):

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

So is it worth it to have my account anymore?  And how do I remove my account from Stack Overflow?

Comment: I think you should have asked "why am I banned from asking questions in StackOverflow"

Comment: @Amarghosh: he (sort of) [did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62192/cant-post-questions-closed), it was closed as a dupe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your first question is up to you. What are you doing now with your SO account? Do you want to continue doing it? If so, keep your SO account (and contact support if you don't know why you can't ask questions). Otherwise, you may consider closing it.

Your second question is answered by [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account).

Comment: hm thanxs only thing we are here is to post question and dig answers and they disabled those what else i can do. as a programmer i have many doubts each sec even :)

Comment: @Gobi Then you are answering your own question.

Comment: Why doesnn't StackExchange just put up an honest message? You've been blocked because you annoyed the community. We think you're a pest and we're sick of closing your questions.

Answer (score 34):

The block on asking questions is reversible, if you can show that you've changed your ways by posting good quality answers.

As you're already aware, the block on asking questions stems from consistently asking questions of a poor quality.  This is automated based on the votes on your questions.  Looking at your account, you only have one question with a negative score (it's possible some were deleted). It's also possible your many questions with low views and no answers were also taken into account.

This is an example of one of your questions, the one that has a score of -1:

> #### Facebook like link sharing module in drupal or Screen Scrapping with images?
>
> Hi,
>
> im looking for a module or class file if user provide an url and its show output of title,desc, with images as same like facebook link share works
>
> anyone have idea plz share,
>
> Thanxs, Gobi

Firstly, this question is so poorly written that it's bound to attract downvotes.  Users specializing in this field might be able to work out the gist of what you're asking for, but many users will just see this question as junk.  Frankly, I'm surprised you only received one downvote for this question.

Secondly, it looks like you're specifically asking for code, not for help writing the code.  Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A website.  It's for programmers to ask programming related questions and receive programming related answers.  Asking for someone to give you a plugin to do what you're asking isn't asking for programming help, because you're not doing any programming.  Asking for code is almost always met with downvotes and close votes.

It's clear at this point that English isn't your first language (if it is, then may God have mercy on your soul!).  Although I can sympathize that it might be difficult to write questions clearly in a language you don't write/speak in very well, it's not an excuse.  In fact, it's even more of a reason to add more detail and examples to your question.  If we can see that you've put effort into your post, someone will almost certainly edit your question to make more sense.

Things you can do to improve your questions:

- Add as much detail as you can without repeating yourself or rambling.
- Avoid shortening words like *"please"* to *"plz"*.
- Try and avoid using phrases like *"please share"*, this is synonymous with asking for someone to do your work for you.
- Show the code that you've written so far.  If you don't have the slightest clue as to what you're trying to do, you might be better off reading some tutorials first.
- Post images that illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

Having the ban lifted will most probably require you to have a positive involvement on the "A" part of the site, writing answers to questions.  If you think you can help others, you should make an effort to do so.  Writing some quality answers will show that you have seen the error of your ways and you can ask here for the ban to be lifted.

Of course, if you don't want to put this effort in then Stack Overflow might not be the right place for you.  You can leave your account as it is or you can ask for it to be deleted.

Comment: This is a very good rundown on how to write better questions, and should be pinned somewhere near the site's entrance for every newbie to see. If in this case, however, the user was banned based on some automatic algorithm, that algorithm is broken IMO, as this is by far not the worst user, and many of his questions *are* rather intelligible. As far as I can see, it is also not really his fault that he has so many unanswered questions - there are a few dupes that never gained enough close votes, etc. I'm a bit worried about what is going on here.

Comment: @Pekka: I was wondering the same thing when I was looking through his profile.  Of course, we can't see if he has any deleted questions with negative scores and it would be safe to assume they would be factored in.

Comment: @Andy well im not a English geek but still i do ma best i can. 

"Facebook like link sharing module in drupal or Screen Scrapping with images?" 

just look at the wording i made just bcoz to turn other user to hit ma question.

"fb like link sharing module" if you are web developer then you should know wht it means for sure.

"Screen Scrapping" the well known word for web devlopers.

what else wrong in this lol and the answer for that question is below url
http://tiny.cc/a6tdc

and i know this code leads to privacy issue but  developer do what client needs.

Comment: @pekka thnxs dude just created a new account thats yet.                                                                    
@Andy i tried to delete some question to but it throwing alert wait till 2 days tomo etc. So i left as it is & its waste of time too. So i go with new login andy thanxs anyway for ur brief history

Comment: @Gobi: I did say in my answer that some users would understand what you're asking for, but some others (even drupal and FB experts) would read it as a junk post.  But that wasn't the only case I made against your question being poor.  I think the best thing you could do is take a look at some good quality questions that have a few upvotes and you might understand what you're doing wrong.  Creating another account to work around your block might not be taken lightly by the moderators.

Comment: @Gobi: I don't care about the grammar, but words like "bcoz", "wht", "i" and "ur" are typical for chat/street/sms style of English writing. This is not appreciated in serious conversations. I'd almost say that you know this yourself very good as well.

Comment: @Andy fine andy my question is always hard to answer so no worry about it and im not here for race, just need my solution thats all. So im ready to create anymore login or will find some othe r stackoverflow no worry. :) have a nice day andy

Comment: @all since nice peoples are here like  @Daniel,@pekka,@andy,more.. and they have passionate to understand ma question properly, even the question isn't right format and thats why im still stick with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: it shows that the SO moderation system works, works well.