# Why can't I ask questions on StackOverflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)

When I click on the `Post your Question` button SO tells me the following:

**Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
    * Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.**

What is the problem?  Or am I blocked from asking questions on SO?

My reputation is 63 in SO.

Comment: Please search before you ask. Occasional duplicates are unavoidable, but old questions are publicly available/searchable for a reason. This has been asked several times and can easily be found from a search of the error message itself. Usually, I don't leave comments like this, but in this case it seems relevant.

Comment: @YOU, cleaning up here, created [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We have a heuristic in place that stops users from asking questions if we notice a lot of downvotes for a users.

It looks like you tripped the heuristic, but just by a tiny bit. If you provide one or two more quality answers that get upvoted you will be able to ask questions again.

Comment: Additionally, it seems like he has asked duplicate questions and questions which already exist in that form or another.

Comment: Again, if the questions visible are all questions asked, the heuristic is *way* too harsh. I'm glad about every leech that gets booted out this way, but this doesn't seem to be one of them

Comment: @pekka we also include deleted posts in our calculations

Comment: @waffles: I believe he already knows that since he specified **if the questions visible are all questions asked**. It would be nice if you could tell us if he has any downvoted deleted questions, though.

Comment: @Kop yes, but we are not going to release our algorithm cause it will be gamed, personally I see this as a failing of, us, the community. When you see question/answers by users with less than say 200 rep or so, please upvote if you want them to continue asking questions on the site.

Comment: for example, @Tareq is probably missing only 2-3 upvotes, that could easily be fixed ...

Comment: @waffles is it automatic as well, or does a moderator need to manually lift the ban?

Comment: @Shadow automatic

Comment: Oops. Going to update wrong comment then. :/

Comment: What about me, A asked a perfectly good question, which was downvotes a lot and now i can't ask question anymore. I triggered the heuristic too.

Comment: @Starx on meta? you asked 5 questions most of which got heavily downvoted, take some time off... look at existing questions on meta and provide some interesting answers to lift the ban

Comment: i asked 1 question that was voted to be moved to another shelf. also recently i deleted some of these "bad" questions thinking it would help me be able to ask questions again. now ive learnt it will give me more negative points. anyhow, its a bad system if a new user who has only asked 3 questions is banned when he is still getting used to the site. maybe there should be a leeway period for new users, negative points accumulate and user is banned from asking questions but they can restore the points (visibly). atm its just, ask some more questions, and maybe your ip might get privileges back.

Comment: @jskye you are not banned from answering, answer a few questions well and your ban will be lifted

Comment: waffles the rule is good, but sometimes i think it is targetting the wrong people. I was happy to contribute on Stack Overflow and occassionally asked a question which got downvoted. I deleted one particular question as well after I saw that it was not so wise but nowhere anything that would justify a ban. I mean if someone like me has a reputation of 492 he should a least be gotten a warning first, dont you think?

Comment: me too, i really don't like this rule. i wanted to ask and also contribute

Comment: @waffles I am also bloked but dont how to lift the block. My rep was 150 and now it is 900 I answered many questions but this is not helping at all. _How much sure can I be that the  heuristic will notice my contribution?_

Comment: Same is happening to me, my rep was 20, now its 427, and still not able to  ask ? how many years does this  question ban last ??

Comment: How much is "a lot" of downvotes?

Comment: "If you provide one or two more quality answers that get upvoted you will be able to ask questions again."

I have answered a lot of questions on stackoverflow. I have a reputation of 595. Then why I am still not able to post questions?

I mean it's ok you stop people from asking silly questions, but if two of my questions got downvoted and at the same time I contribute in this community, then I don't think I should be banned from asking further questions.

Comment: I believe that I have asked good questions, I've always tried to keep them clear and focused and well structured. Sometimes a question is a duplicate because I couldn't think of the correct wording to search but I think others can also have this problem and find the correct answer through my questions. Also I don't have downvotes on my questions, they just lack upvotes so I dont quite understand why I got banned :(

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas I completely agree, too! The main problem I face here is that I got banned from asking questions (somewhat legit too) on SO, but most of my questions are neutral. I can't expect a perfect website *anywhere* (that's just not how things work), but I at least want to see more going in to prevent people from getting banned faster than thanos' snap unfairly. I've now thought to say "use stack exchange, but don't use it personally: doing so will destroy your pride". It's a paradox for some people because asking 1 question to get them out every 6 months is oftentimes not enough.

Comment: @waffles in addition, I think a six month ban is quite overkill. Within 1-2 days I had a good idea on how to ask questions already via self-reflection (I *did* kind of rush questions before that). I think  people should get a 1 day question ban before going onto a more severe ban, and even that should be lowered to 2-3 months (I went straight to the ban with no warning whatsoever). Also, upvoting isn't that common anymore.This causes a problem because there *are* quality questions/answers that just don't get upvoted, making it harder to lift the ban.

Comment: "If you provide one or two more quality answers that get upvoted you will be able to ask questions again" - are you sure?  Has this been changed?  Because I've been stuck in a question ban for a long time and the system doesn't seem to care that I've posted numerous well-received answers.

Comment: Can you please check my account? It has been more than an year still I am not able to ask questions?