# How can a user get out of a question ban when questions can't be improved?

Tags: support, post-ban

What if a user is banned from asking questions and there is no choice for him/her to improve his/her questions, will that user be banned permanently from asking questions on SO?

Comment: We don't know for sure. If there are only a few problematic questions, providing good answers may be enough to lift the ban. That said, in what case would a user have "no choice to improve his / her questions"?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68885/187824).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There *is* a way to lift the question ban without improving the questions: post answers! But make sure that these answers are high-quality and get upvoted. If a question-banned user gets also a lot of downvoted answers, then he will also get *answer*-banned.

Comment: Are you sure? there is no such explanation  on help center

Comment: @Pavan See this [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/168333): "If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure."

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thank you. That helped

Comment: I did this in MathOverflow, but this didn't help. So I deleted permanently the contribution to MathOverflow.

Comment: I also permanently deleted my account for Math StackExchange because my net score for questions was less than -20 and one of my good answers had got downvoted and deleted.

Comment: The question limit is here one question per 6 months. So the best is to wait 6 hours if the best possible fixing questions lowers the user's net score. Possibly the user is unlucky since the user's questions are not useful and therefore get downvoted by some users.

Comment: Also, undeleting a question with score 1 or more (or possibly even 0) may help to get out of a question ban, and similarly undeleting answered questions. Never delete any questions with an accepted answersince this still counts towards a question ban. Undeleting questions with an accepted answer can help.